# What exactly is Binding Energy and how is Energy released in a Nuclear Fusion?

Tags: energy-conservation, nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

Binding Energy of a nucleus can be found using the formula
$$E = \Delta m\,c^2$$

Here, $\Delta m$ is the mass defect of the nucleus. Now, in a nuclear fusion reaction, we combine two lighter elements into a heavier element. But in this reaction, the total mass of initial two elements is greater than the heavier element. So some mass $\Delta m$ is converted to energy. **But shouldn't this released energy ($\Delta m\,c^2$) go into forming the binding energy for the nucleus?** But then why energy is still released into the surroundings?

Answer (score 2):

Nuclear binding energy is the energy that has to be *added* to a nucleus in order to separate it into its constituent protons and neutrons. Another way of thinking about it is that it is the net energy that would be *released* if you pushed a bunch of protons and neutrons together so tightly than the short range strong nuclear force combined them into a nucleus.

Since the binding energy is always positive, the mass of a nucleus is *smaller* than the sum of the masses of its individual nucleons. So binding energy is sometimes referred to as the [mass defect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Mass_defect) or mass deficit of a nucleus.

The key number is the average binding energy per nucleon. This is a minimum value for hydrogen (which has zero binding energy since its nucleus is a single proton), increases from hydrogen up to iron, and then decreases again for elements further along the periodic table than iron (this is a slight simplification - there is a chart of the actual shape of the curve [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#/media/File:Binding_energy_curve_-_common_isotopes.svg)).

So if you fuse two nuclei that are lighter than iron, the mass defect of the fused nucleus is *greater than* the mass defect of the original nuclei. Since the mass defect goes *up*, the mass of the combined nucleus is *smaller than* the combined masses of the original nuclei, and the “missing” mass is released as energy. Similarly, if you split or fission a nucleus that is heavier than iron the mass defect also goes up, and energy is released.

Comment: `the mass of the combined nucleus is smaller than the combined masses of the original nuclei, and the “missing” mass is released as energy` . Yes, and shouldn't this same "missing" mass convert into binding energy for holding the combined nuclei together?

Comment: @ Jdeep No. The mass defect *is* the binding energy. You don't have to add more energy when you fuse light nuclei - instead some of the binding energy present in the original nuclei is "repaid" and released into the environment. If you owe your brother two loans of \$25 each but he agrees to cancel the whole debt if you repay him \$30 then you are \$20 better off than you were before.

Comment: IMHO, it'd be less confusing if it were called the "unbinding energy".